# elasticsearch search query returns "hits" blank

Tags: elasticsearch

I am fairly new to elasticsearch and I've been trying to make searches on my data and always get the hits section to be empty.This happens even after the data is uploaded and indexed. My mapping is as follows:

```
{
    "mappings":{
        "type":{
            "properties":{
                "adoriId":{
                    "type":"integer"
                },
                "custom":{
                    "type":"nested",
                    "properties":{
                        "timestamp":{
                            "type":"text"
                        },
                        "value":{
                            "type":"text"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to obtain the associated timestamp value for the text searched. The search query that I use (Using postman)

GET http://localhost:9200/transcripts/type/_search

```
{
    "query":{
        "match":{
            "custom.value":"iTunes to rate review And subscribe"
        }
    }
}
```

Any search I make returns this

```
{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 0,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field `custom` is of [Nested Datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) for which you need to make use of [Nested Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html).

Below is how your query must be:

```
GET transcripts/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "nested":{  
         "path":"custom",
         "query":{  
            "match":{  
               "custom.value":"iTunes to rate review And subscribe"
            }
         },
         "inner_hits":{}
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! But how do I get the associated timestamp value for the phrase search ?

Comment: Sorry, could you provide an example. You do get the entire document as response using the above query and it must have the `timestamp`(which should be `date` datatype instead and not `text`) field returned.

Comment: @SiddeshwarRaghavan I've added `inner_hits` to the query. Let me know if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, inner_hits is what I was looking for. Thank you for your help.